# How to disable strange Android Studio comment indentation?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I'm seeing a strange thing happening in Android Studio. This is with Kotlin. In an `if` block, if there is a comment before a return statement, and I hit enter at the end of the comment to presumably write some code (or even another comment), it indents as if it's a new block:

```
    fun someFun() {
        if (true) {
            // Some comment
                // Wants me to indent???
                    // And again...
                        // And again...
            return
        }
    }
```

It's driving me up the wall and I can't figure out why this behavior is happening or how to disable it. If the `return` statement isn't there, this doesn't happen. It also only happens inside an `if` block. Any help would be much appreciated.